# Want to return a value that matches a surname and first name but where first name has alternative spelling so want to match just first 3 characters

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I am looking to use the Index formula to return a value for a student to give me their student ID that matches surname and first name. I have a formula that works but the issues is that I am using data from two different data sources and the spelling for some names is different. I have attempted to use the left function to only look for the first couple of letters but my understanding of this function means I am only getting NA.
This is the code that works for most students

```
=INDEX('Student Details'!C2:'Student Details'!C146,MATCH(1,('Student Details'!E2:'Student Details'!E146=Consolidated!B2)*('Student Details'!G2:'Student Details'!G146=Consolidated!C2),0))
```

This is my attempt at adding the left function to the fourmula

```
=INDEX('Student Details'!C12:'Student Details'!C156,MATCH(1,('Student Details'!E12:'Student Details'!E156=Consolidated!B12)*('Student Details'!G12:'Student Details'!G156=LEFT(Consolidated!C12,3)),0))
```

I am importing data from our schools student management system as well as an online report which pulls data from a different data set and this data has exact legal names wheres as the other data has name preferred.

edit* I need the surname and first name as we have a lot of students with the same last name

Answer (score 0):

As an easy solution I'd suggest simply inserting a helper column in sheet `Consolidated`. Cell `D2` in `Consolidated` for example would have the following formula (just copy the formula down to match you complete dataset):

```
=LEFT(C2,3)
```

Your updated `INDEX & MATCH` formula would look like this (please note that sheet & cell references can be used in this shortened version):

```
=INDEX('Student Details'!$C$2:$C$146,MATCH(1,('Student Details'!$E$2:$E$146=Consolidated!$B2)*('Student Details'!$G$2:$G$146=Consolidated!$D2),0))
```

You should also use absolute cell references for referencing the dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got that to work. After sleeping on it though I was able to get it to work without having to use a helper column, I was just getting the configuration of the brackets wrong!